# Can't find AU Lab on Mac

Tags: mac, xcode, ios

Can't find AU Lab on my Mac mini.

I have Xcode installed. Where can I find the program?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With Xcode 4.3, the Lion App Store version, Xcode was unified to a single application. At the same time Apple removed some of the smaller utilities to save space on the download. Some of the utilities can be launched from inside Xcode, others are available as a separate download.

AU Lab is in the package "Audio Tools for Xcode" available in the [Downloads for Apple Developers](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action) page.

Comment: I have found a direct link to AU lab and some other apple audio tools if you want to cherry pick what you need: http://www.apple.com/itunes/mastered-for-itunes/

Comment: While that was very useful in 2013, the current AU Lab is not what you get from that link, but is a 2012 Intel app. 
Log in at Developer with your Apple ID, use the answer link and look for "Additional Tools for Xcode" where you'll find current AU Lab as well as HAL Lab, both Universal. The newest at the time of post is 14.3 RC or 14.2.